# Entire function defined by infinite product

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working on the following problem:

> Suppose $|w|<1$. Prove that the function
> $$ f(z)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+w^{2n-1}e^z)(1+w^{2n-1}e^{-z}) $$
> is entire.

I know of a theorem that states, if $(f_n)$ is a sequence of holomorphic functions defined on a domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb C$ and the series $\sum(1-f_n)$ converges uniformly and absolutely on compact subsets of $\Omega$, then the function $f=\prod f_n$ is holomorphic.

I don't know if this theorem can be applied here - any help on this problem is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it applies here; an infinite product of the form $$\prod_n(1+h_n)$$ converges uniformly and absolutely when the infinite series $\sum_nh_n$ also converges uniformly and absolutely. Now consider that term in your product expression is $$(1+w^{2n-1}e^z)(1+w^{2n-1}e^{-z})=1+\left(2w^{2n-1}\cosh(z)+ w^{4n-2}\right)\,.$$ Clearly, because $|w|<1$, we have the easy evaluation $$\sum_n \left(2w^{2n-1}\cosh(z)+ w^{4n-2}\right)=2\frac{w}{1-w^2}\cosh(z)+\frac{w^2}{1-w^4}\,;$$
hence, your infinite product converges uniformly and absolutely (in compact subsets) for all $z$ and is therefore entire.